# Signal a u-turn to road users

Tags: safety, signals

I am living in the UK and in this situation (sorry for my bad drawing):

[image]

The bike (the dot in front) wants to do a u-turn and needs to signal to the car (the dot behind). If the bike does not signal, the car will not slow down and my hit the bike.

How can I signal a u-turn? I was thinking about putting my hand behind me but that may not be obvious for road users.

Comment: For reference, the Highway Code details 3 kinds of hand signals for cyclists: left, right and slowing down/stop. see https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/signals-to-other-road-users

Comment: That Uturn - good chance you won't be 'living' in the UK long.

Comment: No, you don't "need to" signal to the car. You just slow down and let the car overtake you, and then make your U turn. But if you really want to make a signal, my experience as a car driver says that if I cyclist turns his/her head round to look behind for long enough to make eye contact with a driver behind the bike, that "signal" usually means "I think I'm immortal, and I'm now going to do something completely stupid just to prove I'm right - try to kill me if you dare".

Comment: Can you simply ride around the block instead ?

Comment: Sorry, but how is this much different from turning right? You just turn... even more right. I'd signal for the right turn, and then - if not hindered by vehicles coming from the right and turning into "my" street - do the U-turn.

Comment: @alephzero Your comment would be a great answer! I encourage you to move it to an answer post. (There's no automatic way to do it. Just copy and paste, then delete the comment.)

Comment: If it wasn't for the junction I was going to say exactly the same as Erik.  I did a couple yesterday and on both occasions signalled right , turned across the road, and checked before moving off again.  It was a quiet road.

Comment: Also, a bike can turn in its own length.  Why go to the end of the road to do a 180 degree turn ?

Comment: If you are conscious about your sketch you may want to consider drawing on paper and using an app like camscanner. Your sketch combined with the written explanation are clear enough, but paper and camscanner (or similar) might be quicker and clearer for this sort of situation. NB this is not intended as advertising.

Comment: @alephzero: As a cyclist, if I signal and turn around long enough to make eye contact with you, it means “I know very well that you’re controlling a large, fast hunk of metal, and I can’t turn right if you don’t want me to.  So I’m asking you to let me turn right, and I’m hoping that as a responsible and co-operative fellow road user, you’ll be fine with that.”  Then if you seem to be acknowledging the eye contact and slowing down, I’ll take that as indicating agreement, and I’ll (still cautiously) start to move out.  Am I being too optimistic in my interpretation of your actions?

Comment: If your own life was all you were risking that might be fine but it it isn't, is it?

There are countries where getting a driving licence is almost easier than falling off a log, though yours might not be one of them.

Still, if this is a serious Question why not book an afternoon with a driving instructor who could update your skills?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, don't attempt a u-turn at a junction where you may have vehicles approaching from multiple directions and vehicle drivers will be expecting you to make a left or right turn, not a u-turn.

U turn away at a point where you can see both directions clearly - away from blind turns and rises. Wait until vehicle have passed you to turn, If you need to get vehicles past, stop and wave them by.

You can also more safely u-turn by turning right or left onto a minor side road (or driveway, carpark etc), turning around there, then making the opposite turn back onto the major road.

Comment: Agree, I wouldn't venture into the relative danger of that junction. Traffic will be going at least 30mph, more often than not. Good alternative suggestions

Comment: ... in other words at a place where it doesn't matter whether you do a "only" a right turn (say into a driveway) or a U turn since both imply that you cross *all* other traffic and thus the signal that you will turn right does not have any relevant ambiguity.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers have good notes about doing this more safely. But if the car is far enough behind you and you are sure there is no risk, **just signal a right turn**. Your path will be almost the same, and the reaction needed from the driver is the same (increased awareness, possibly need to slow down).

I myself would only do this if the distance was so large that the car doesn't really need to slow down, so the signal is given just to avoid giving them unnecessary surprises. Otherwise I would just wait for the car to pass before crossing the road.

Comment: the car will have to slow down at a point as well - simply because there is no road ahead after the T-junction. I would worry more about the "offending" traffic on both sides of the junction - if there is nothing, just indicate right - and drive along your path

Comment: In an ideal world this would be safe, as no sensible driver will try and overtake you during the right-turn. However, I think it's more than possible for a driver to assume you are going to turn right, attempt to overtake, which would result in you being cut up as you completed the U-turn. You might be in the right, but you'd be "dead right". Bad drivers are unpredictable.

Comment: The more reason to not to cling to the kerb, but - especially at intersections - to keep to the middle of the lane @Kialandei

Comment: @Kialandei: no, it wouldn't be safe at the depicted crossing even in an ideal world: someone coming from the right who wants to turn left, i.e. into the opposite direction of where OP comes from could safely turn while OP does a normal right turn. But not with a U turn.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Depends on *if* there is someone simultaneously coming from the right. Presumably the bicyclist at the depicted position would see and hear them already.

Answer (score 5):

I think the legal way is to get off your bike before reaching the cross street, (about where your arrow is,) cross walking, and get on your bike again.
The signal you need in that case is a hand up and down, on the side of the pavement (side walk) where you will stop. But this signal is gone out of fashion in many countries.

What you want to do might be acceptable when there is no traffic on both roads, but any car will be confused and you will be in the danger zone.

Comment: Calling this the legal way implies other ways could be illegal, but cycling in the UK is pretty liberal, there are few hard [rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-cyclists-59-to-82) and U-turns are typically legal for road users unless prohibited by a sign. The rules _do_ focus on safety though and this method certainly promotes caution by crossing on foot.

Comment: Perhaps substitute "safest" for "legal"?

Comment: I am not from the UK but what I see when there and when reading about cycling in the UK is that many cyclists ignore the laws and rules, not that there are no laws and rules. I do not say (or even imply) that a U-turn is illegal, it is certainly not taught in cycling lessons and it is not what drivers would expect you to do, making it dangerous if done in the wrong spot.

Comment: I don't think that "legal" is a very bad wording, though you could say "legitimate" if that makes you feel better. While something isn't _illegal_ if the law doesn't forbid it (that's right!) there's still being "illegal" when it's endangering and against normal practice. The reason why so many cyclists die (and why car drivers hate them with a passion) is that a majority of cyclists believes that they're alone on the street, and need not follow any rules because rules don't apply to them (red traffic light, who cares!). Sudden, unexpected (and unnecessary) moves are dangerous to everyone.